# Applying Threshold mask

Tags: matlab

i am making image compression in matlab.

After i applied DCT on image and i had img matrix, i want to apply a threshold mask on that matrix.

```
mask =     [1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0
            1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
            1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
            1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
            0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0];

maskedImg = blkproc(img,[8 8],mask );
```

I used that function but it didnt work and i get error message:

Error in ==> blkproc at 67
[a, block, border, fun, params, padval] = parse_inputs(varargin{:});

Comment: Did you read the docs for `blkproc`?  In particular, the description of the `fun` argument?

Comment: i did i have tried that   myAveFun = @(mask) size(mask);    

maskedImg = blkproc(C,[8 8],myAveFun ) . But its not still working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to latest `Matlab` documentation; closest [blockproc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/blockproc.html) syntax (for your case) is `B = blockproc(A,[M N],fun)`. So apparently your `mask` really should be a function!

However, I recall that `blkproc` has been a valid `Matlab` function for a while ago, thus double check the proper way to call it by typing (in the command line) `> help blkproc`. (Al tough I'm quite confident that it will share the calling signature with `blockproc` [in this case]).